# SCM Manager REST POST xml returns 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, xml, rest, post, jersey-client

I am trying to post an XML content using SCM Manager (v1.46) through REST. Using cURL from command line works fine:

```
call curl -XPOST -u scmadmin:scmadmin -H "content-type: application/xml" -d "<users><name>abc</name><active>true</active><password>abc</password><displayName>abc</displayName><mail>abc@abc.com</mail><type>xml</type><lastModified/><creationDate/><admin>false</admin></users>" http://localhost:8080/scm/api/rest/users.xml
```

and the user **abc** is created. My Java client, using Jersey, gets a **415 Unsupported Media Type** response from SCM Manager. The client looks like this:

```
...

public WebResource getService(String p_url, String p_user, String p_password) {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(p_user, p_password));
    return client.resource(getBaseURI(p_url));
}

...

public Document postXmlDocument(String p_url, String p_user, String p_password, String p_xml) {
    WebResource service = getService(p_url, p_user, p_password);
    Document xmlDocument = null;
    ClientResponse response = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(ClientResponse.class, p_xml); 
    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
    }
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println("Server response : \n");
    System.out.println(output);
    return xmlDocument;
}
```

where the **p_xml** gets the same content like in the cURL command. Isn't enogh to set the accepted media type by using the **MediaType.APPLICATION_XML**? The used Jersey has this Maven coordinate:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId> 
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Any hint would be good.
SK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Accept` only says the type you want back. You need to set the `Content-Type` to tell the server what type you are sending. If you don't it will just default to some unexpected type. For example if you send a String, it might default to `Content-Type: text/plain`. There server can't convert plain text to your POJO, so you get a 415 unsupported media type.

You call [`type(String|MediaType)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#type%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29) to set the content type, or use [`header(String, String)`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#header%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).type("application/xml")..

service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).header("Content-Type", "application/xml")...
```

Comment: Yes, the accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).type("application/xml") is the solution for this problem. It is the time to read he source of jersey API. Thank you, SK